# Instrumentation of Mysql Jpa Repository in Spring using AWS X-Ray not working

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, aws-xray

I am trying to instrument Mysql calls using AWS X-Ray in my spring application. http and s3 instrumentation is working fine.

I have set the property: `spring.datasource.jdbc-interceptors=com.amazonaws.xray.sql.mysql.TracingInterceptor`

I have included following dependancies in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-spring'
compile("com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core")
compile("com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk")
compile("com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-instrumentor")
compile("com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-apache-http")
compile("com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-sql-mysql")
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom('com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-bom:1.3.1')
    }
}
```

I am using JpaRepositories. I am expecting all my sql queries to get instrumented automatically after above setup is done. I am following amazon doc at this location:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-sqlclients.html

What am I missing?

Update: I can see mysql traces for spring's health endpoint. But jpa calls are still unseen.

Comment: Hi, did you ever resolve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you constructing the `DataSource` object using the defined `spring.datasource` properties in your `application.properties`?

See this `dataSource()` method ([GitHub](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-java-scorekeep/blob/xray/src/main/java/scorekeep/RdsWebConfig.java#L55)) in the `RdsWebConfig` class which uses the `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")` annotation in order to pick up the relevant `jdbc-interceptors` property.

Hope this helps.

James

Comment: As far as I understand, if you rely on Spring autoconfiguration to initialize your DataSource, this shouldn't be necessary. I'm assuming OP sets up the database credentials via Spring properties as well which arguably are picked up.